# Haskell: Parse error in an IO program

Tags: haskell, parse-error

I am writing a program to help my younger brother learn addition. I am not experienced in writing IO programs, And I am stuck with this parse error:

```
MyCode.hs:6:25:
    Parse error in pattern: show
    Possibly caused by a missing 'do'?
```

The code:

```
mathExercise times (a,b) = 
    if times<=0
    then return ()
    else do let x = randInt a
            let y = randInt b 
            putStr (show x ++ " + "++ show y++ " = ")
            ans <- getInt
            if (ans==x+y)
            then do print True
                    mathExercise (times-1) (a,b)
            else do print False
```

Comment: Could you tell us what the error you are seeing is?

Comment: I might as well tell you that this isn't going to work. Haskell has no `randInt` function that works in the way you expect. Do some research on Haskell random-number generation, or consider using a different language for this task.

Comment: @AJFarmar no big deal as he is already in `IO` - just use [`randomIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html#v:randomIO) - to the op: you should use this with something like ``fmap (`mod` 10) randomIO`` to get it into range ;)

Comment: randInt is a function that depends on the Time.

Comment: `randomInt :: Integer -> IO Integer

randomInt n = 
    do
      time <- getCurrentTime
      return ( (`rem` n) $ read $ take 6 $ formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%q" time)

-- Extract the random number from the IO monad, unsafely!

randInt :: Integer -> Integer

randInt = unsafePerformIO . randomInt`

Comment: The code is really sexy!

Answer (score 8):

You have mixed tabs and spaces. The code you posted has tabs in the following places (marked with `--->`)

```
mathExercise times (a,b) = 
    if times<=0
--->then return ()
--->else do let x = randInt a
--->        let y = randInt b 
--->        putStr (show x ++ " + "++ show y++ " = ")
--->--->--->ans <- getInt
--->--->--->if (ans==x+y)
--->--->--->then do print True
--->--->--->--->--->mathExercise (times-1) (a,b)
--->--->--->else do print False
```

Assuming there exist correct `getInt` and `randInt` declarations, the code will compile with the same layout if all of the tabs are replaced with spaces.

```
mathExercise times (a,b) = 
    if times<=0
    then return ()
    else do let x = randInt a
            let y = randInt b 
            putStr (show x ++ " + "++ show y++ " = ")
            ans <- getInt
            if (ans==x+y)
            then do print True
                    mathExercise (times-1) (a,b)
            else do print False
```

If  `randInt` is actually a random integer in `IO`, you will instead need to write

```
mathExercise times (a,b) = 
    if times<=0
    then return ()
    else do x <- randInt a
            y <- randInt b
            ...
```

using `System.Random`:

```
import System.Random (randomIO)

randInt a = fmap (`mod` a) randomIO

mathExercise times (a,b) = 
    if times<=0
    then return ()
    else do x <- randInt a
            y <- randInt b
            ...
```

Comment: I added one possible implementation using `randomIO` I hope you don't mind - feel free to delete it again if so

Comment: @CarstenKönig Thanks. I was going to add the other one `randInt a = randomRIO (1,a)` but I tripped over the dreaded monomorphism restriction when I defined `getInt = readLn`.

Comment: maybe randomRIO is even nicer (probably easier to understand and your bounds are shifted by 1 which might be desired) - to be honest I did not remember although I must have skimmed it on the docs  - so thanks for the reminder ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the indentation of the if statement and that randInt is an IO operation:

```
mathExercise times (a,b) = 
    if times<=0
    then return ()
    else do x <- randInt a
            y <- randInt b 
            putStr (show x ++ " + "++ show y++ " = ")
            ans <- getInt
            if (ans==x+y)
               then do print True
                       mathExercise (times-1) (a,b)
               else do print False
            -- ^ Indented here
```

Comment: This is valid. Now, go ahead and try to make a pure `randInt` function! :P

Comment: sorry,  I wasn't sure what randInt was suppose to do

Comment: randomInt n = 
    do
      time <- getCurrentTime
      return ( (`rem` n) $ read $ take 6 $ formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%q" time)

-- Extract the random number from the IO monad, unsafely!

randInt :: Integer -> Integer

randInt = unsafePerformIO . randomInt